# sql select not working with hash

Tags: php, sql

I'm still new at php and I can't understand what's wrong here. I have a php script and I'm using it as a login script (simple functionality behind it since I'm still learning). I've ensured that the input values in the form match the ones in the mysql database. Code below is the sql causing the issue:

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `golden_acres_username` WHERE `uname`='$username' AND `password`='$password_hash'"
```

When I change the above code to the one below it works (The difference is that I manually insert the md5 hash) :

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `golden_acres_username` WHERE `uname`='$username' AND `password`='81dc9bdb52d04dc20036'"
```

Variables set are:

```
$login_button = $_POST['login_button'];             
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];                 
$password_hash = md5($_POST['password']);
```

Can anyone kindly explain where I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `golden_acres_username` 
WHERE `uname`='".$username."' AND `password`='".$password_hash."'"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :) What effect does that have on the code ?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should look for a more secure password hashing mechanism like [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Second, you have significant SQL injection vulnerability currently as you are not escaping the input no using parametrized prepared statements.

It is really not worth discussing the solution until you at least do the latter of these two.

Comment: I'm simply learning php, I'm sure I will work on security in the near future.

Comment: @joebegborg07 That's fine if you are just learning.  I would just suggest you learn the right way to query the database to prevent against SQL injection.  This should be one of the very first considerations when learning to work with databases.